# how do I get access to javascript event object inside tag

Tags: javascript

How do I access the onTouchstart event from the html attribute? Is there a way of doing this?

```
<img src="img/ui/arrow-left.svg" ontouchstart="e.preventDefault(); /*my code here*/ ">
```

I'd prefer not to have to do something like

```
el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);

function handleStart(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   //my code here
}
```

Comment: I would prefer keeping javascript out of the elements... but if you want to do it inline, try `event` instead of `e` - http://jsfiddle.net/j2yje1w1/

Comment: Why do you prefer not to do the second option?

Comment: That is it event instead of e thanks all

Comment: @FishBasketGordo for short functions I find it much more readable to have the javascript inline. otherwise I have to find where in all the javascript code I added the event handler. So I guess the answer is personal preference.

Comment: If you want to learn more about event handling, I recommend to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, your preferred method of inline event handling is considered poor practice. You and your application would be much better off with abstracted event handling.

Inline event handling reduces maintainability and readability. However, it does not reduce performance either way you go. If you pulled up a website to others and it uses inline scripting, there will be instant critisism of your work. Not to mention (from the programmers answer on this (cannot paste links for some reason)) that HTML and CSS files should only contain that -- all javascript is better put in a seperate file to abstract the view from the controller. Readability and maintainability are more important that having a script / site that simply works.

Since `event` is not defined as a callback parameter, it defaults to `event` not `e`.

Comment: While this is true, it's not an answer to the OPs question. This should be a comment.

Comment: Knew I left out something.

Comment: @dystroy I added reasons, but I'm experiencing a copy paste bug so I can't give proper citations yet :(